# Whats the newest version of the install4j-maven-plugin?

Tags: install4j

I was looking to the [maven plugin website](http://sonatype.github.io/install4j-support/install4j-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) for install4j for the newest version and there the version 1.0.8 is noticed. I tried to set this version to my project configuration and it fails said the plugin do not exists in this version. Now I looked to the [central maven repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.sonatype.install4j%22%20AND%20a%3A%22install4j-maven-plugin%22) and there no 1.0.8 exists but newer versions like 1.1.0 and 1.1.1. So what is the recommended plugin version to build a viewer with install4j version 6.x? Anybody knows? Also anybody knows where I can find the docu for the new versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2016-04-07, the current release is 1.1.1. Probably sonatype has not updated the website since 1.0.8. The documentation is available at

http://sonatype.github.io/install4j-support/install4j-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html

Comment: I thought so but are there some important changes from 1.0.8 up to 1.1.1? Because the documentation seems to be for version 1.0.8.

Comment: The list of commits is at https://github.com/sonatype/install4j-support/commits/master